# How do I see suggested edits while review-banned?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits, review-suspension

Yesterday I failed another review audit and got a two day ban - ok, the fact that a lot of these audits don't fit the current policies is another issue, but today I got a little brown flag on the topbar with a suggested edit. I'm assuming this means that someone has edited one of my posts.

How do I find out which post it was? If I click the flag I just get the message about failing too many reviews and come back tomorrow. At the least, I'd like to identify the post in question so I can check back later.

Comment: You mean the one in the top right-middle? It means that someone has suggested an edit... not necessarily to one of your posts

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards oh, yes, that's the one I mean - so why do I get the flag then? People suggest edits all the time - is this something new?

Comment: No, it's always been there (save for the last few weeks). It used to be only shown to people with 10k. I assume the new implementation is seen be everyone.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Thanks - I don't have 10k yet (but I'm close), maybe it's a rounding error ;-)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Yes, now it's shown to everyone. Earlier, I didn't see it, but now I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to your profile, and go to the *responses* tab. Select *revisions* and then you see which post was edited.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I can see that now and like @benisuǝqbackwards commented above, it's not one of my posts, which is confusing.